# what is the recommended architecture for a point-to-point live streaming app?

Tags: video-streaming

I have been asked to design the architecture for a live streaming app. The setup is the following:

- The client has one or more cameras capable of mpjeg and h264 video capture, and a gateway device that controls the cameras (this device is coded by us, so we could if needed get the video stream and redirect it to somewhere else).
- The user can request to see video from one of the cameras in a client web or an android/ios app.
- Upnp is forbidden
- Latency should be as low as possible (~3 seconds)

So with these requirements, I am thinking that the *best* solution would be to redirect an MJPEG stream to an intermediate server, and have the end applications obtain the stream from this server. The problem I see with this solution is the scalability due to large bandwith requirements in the server.

I have seen several solutions in the maket, for example with cameras for controlling babies that diplay the video on your phone, and I wonder what solutions they adopt. Do they simply rely on Upnp? Is there any easier solution I did not think of?

I apologize for the *openness* of the question, but I am quite clueless.

Comment: You should clarify what it is that you don't like about UPnP usage...

Comment: It is a requirement from my boss. He wants a solution that works in all cases, and Upnp does not work always.

Comment: Nothing works in *all* cases.  What specifically about UPnP not working is the issue?  UPnP can be used for a ton of things...

Answer (score 0):

WebRTC is a stack of technologies that meets your requirements.  In there, you have low latency video streaming, peer-to-peer connectivity (where possible), and NAT traversal.  It can be used from the web or native apps.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will investigate this option.

Comment: The company I work for, Frozen Mountain, works with WebRTC. (https://www.frozenmountain.com). 

We have products and services that can help you along.